# Access variables from actions in YII

Tags: php, yii

I have two functions in my controller. There are few fields in my view(say name, email). When I'm trying to access them from function1 it does not work.
It says 
undefined variable:name (it is also defined in model)

```
public function function1()
{
    $name= $_POST['name'] //displays error
}

public function actionContact()
{
    $model=new ContactForm;
    if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
    {
        $this->function1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If form's html code is autogenerated, try to use `$_POST['ContactForm']['name']`. Or, if you really need to call `function1`, just pass form as a `$model` to `function1` and use it in OOP manner